# Laravel E-mail Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I validate email address and make them unique? my problem is when i save and did not input email it will still stored here is my email

my ***Validation Request***

```
 $this->validate($request, [ 
        'email_ad' => 'required|email|unique:clients'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the column in the clients table like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [ 
    'email_ad' => 'required|email|unique:clients,email'
]);
```

This tells the validation which column to check against

Hope this helps

Comment: Shame you got downvoted. I upvoted you since you have a correct answer  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Yeah some people are just like that.

Answer (score 1):

This help you to validate all the field include email also with customize message

```
 $messages = [
                    'same' => 'The passwords did not match'//customized message
                ];   
         $input = $request->validate([
                        'name' => 'required', //name validation
                        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email', //email validation
                        'phone' => 'required|unique:users|min:10|max:12|numeric', //Phone validation
                        'password' => 'required', //password validation
                        'c_password' => 'required|same:password', //confirm Password validation
                        'gender' => 'required', //field validation
                        'referral_code' => 'nullable',
                    ], $messages);
```

Hope You can understand!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given `ID` during the unique check. For example, consider an `update profile` screen that includes the user's name, `e-mail address`, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is `unique`. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a `validation error` to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address.

Try to use this approach

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$this->validate($request, [
    'email_ad' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('clients')->ignore($client->id),
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this is work for me

```
 'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')],
```